# css two colors of h1

Tags: html, css

i have this CSS code:

```
h1 {
    font-size:22px;
    color:#341C12;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:italic;
}
.h1color h1{
    color:#862E06;
}
```

and this HTML Code

```
<h1>News <span class="h1color">&amp; events</span></h1>
```

but its not working. want i want to do is have the first h1 text to be color #341C12 and the other text to #862E06 with using only 1 h1 tag..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
.h1color h1{
```

Should be:

```
h1 .h1color {
```

The order is `parent child`, if you always just have 1 span, you could also leave out the class, and do:

```
h1 span {
```

Answer (score 5):

The [descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) `.h1color h1` selects all `h1` elements that are descendants of an element with the class *h1color*. But you need all elements with the class *h1color* that are descendants of an `h1` element.

So just change the order of the selectors:

```
h1 .h1color {
    color: #862E06;
}
```