# CSS for changing color of last word in h1

Tags: html, css, colors

I have a website that I am developing using CSS3 and I have `h1` tag for the title:

```
<h1>main title</h1>
```

Now I want the title to be in a different color:

```
<h1>main <span>title</span></h1>
```

So I do:

```css
h1 {
 color: #ddd;
}
h1 span {
 color: #333;
}
```

Is there a way **not** to use the `span` tag and only specify in CSS the last word to be a different color?

Comment: No. You have to explicitly specify the span element, because by default, the children inherit the style properties from the parent, if no more specific selector is specified.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is not possible with pure CSS. However you can use **[lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/)** to get a `::last-word` selector. **CSS-Tricks** has an excelent article on this: [CSS-Tricks: A call for nth-everything](http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/). You can then do the following:

```
h1 {
  color: #f00;
}

/* EDIT: Needs lettering.js. Please read the complete post,
 * before downvoting. Instead vote up. Thank you :)
 */
h1::last-word {
  color: #00f;
}
```

Comment: ::last-word doesn't work for me. That's the reason i down-voted. In which browser does it work for you iblue?

Comment: You need to use lettering.js, it's linked in the answer. It should work for all browsers. If not, please report a bug to the creators.

Comment: This should not be marked as the accepted answer since it's plain wrong. If I'm not mistaken, the plugin just adds a `.char#` pattern to the letters, but does nothing to provide `::last-word`-like support in CSS. The article is just pointing out how useful it would be to have selectors like that, and how lettering.js is filling the gap on it's own (different) way.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Correct usage is `$('h1').lettering('words')` and then selecting with `h1 > span::last-child`

Comment: Answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614088/css-two-colors-of-h1 also useful.

Comment: @Kloar The correct syntax is `:last-child` (only one colon).

Answer (score 12):

"last-word" won't work on every browser; for instance, it doesn't work with Safari. I wouldn't use the  accepted answer. I don't think it's a good idea to import an entire library or plugin just to change the last word of a single title, it's like "killing a bug with a cannon"... Instead I would use a single Javascript function, and a global class. Something like this:

```
<h1>This is my awesome <span class="last-word">title</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .last-word {font-weight:bold; /* Or whatever you want to do with this element */ }
</style>
```

Initially, you would have something like this:

```
<h1 class="title">This is my awesome title</h1>
```

Then, you could initialize a Javascript method to change the last word on $(document).ready() =>

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.title').each(function(index, element) {
            var heading = $(element);
            var word_array, last_word, first_part;

            word_array = heading.html().split(/\s+/); // split on spaces
            last_word = word_array.pop();             // pop the last word
            first_part = word_array.join(' ');        // rejoin the first words together

            heading.html([first_part, ' <span class="last-word">', last_word, '</span>'].join(''));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Good luck.

Comment: I edited my answer, now it works even when there are multiple .title elements.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is not. Only `::first-letter` and `::first-line` exist in CSS. Anything else must be done manually with an element (e.g. `span`).

***Note:** Neither `::first-word` nor `::last-word` are planned, at least not in the [Selectors level 4 spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/).*

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no selector for specific words, see [Selectors Level 3: 2. Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

You have to use the `span` tag or run JavaScript to convert every word into a span containing that word.

Answer (score 3):

Taking iblue's answer but making a bit more sensible.

Use [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) with the following setup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1').lettering('words');
});
```

That will split out any `<h1>` tag into something like so:

```
<h1>
    <span class="word1">Highlight</span>
    <span class="word2">the</span>
    <span class="word3">last</span>
    <span class="word4">word</span>
    <span class="word5">a</span>
    <span class="word6">different</span>
    <span class="word7">color</span>
</h1>
```

Of course we can't just target `.word7` as that might not be the last so we can use the `:last-child` CSS pseudo-class.

```
h1 {
    color: #333;
}

h1 > span:last-child {
    color: #c09;
}
```

Now the last word is a different color. [Check out the live example](http://jsbin.com/vadufemida/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Only thing to be careful about is [support for `:last-child`](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Alast-child)

Comment: Worked fine for me.Can create trouble if there is space betn span and h1.

Answer (score 2):

CSS doesn't really interact with text in that manner. it interacts with elements in the DOM tree. Adding a span around that word is the standard way (that I've seen, at least) of differentiating a piece of text. Just use the span tag, the maintainer of the code will thank you for it.

Answer (score 1):

CSS works on elements... but generally not on the text or data inside an element.  You could use Javascript, if you'd like, to work with the actual text inside of the elements, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no selector in CSS that would refer to the last (or first) word of an element. There are pseudo-elements for first letter and for first line, but words need to be wrapped in containers in order to style them separately.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has no knowledge about words. The only thing existing is :first-letter and :first-line.
A construct like a word and a pseudo element for last are not existing.

If you really want to have a workaround within one element, then you must use javascript to parse the last word out.
I think the way you are going is the best way when you only have a few cases on the page.

If you use it for h1 then you should have it so or so only once on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use lettering.js

CDN :
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.6.1/jquery.lettering.min.js"></script>`

, and add this script into footer for selecting the element and splitting it to words.

For example,
`<script>jQuery('h3').lettering('words')</script>`

Now, if you inspect element and check , the word will be splitted, and class will be there word1, word2, word3 and so on depending on number of words...

[image: lettering js word css]

Now pick that class of word you want to edit, and write CSS for that.

CSS Example :
`.word3 {color : red;}`

and done!

Answer (score 0):

This is another way around it.

1. Create the underline using the after pseudo element
2. Control the width of the underline with "width"

Example:

```
.something:after 
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

I selected a width < 100% so that it fits underneath the text with the letter spacing I wanted. This solution worked well for me.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe with "after" selector

```
element1
{
    properties
    main
}

element1:after 
{
    content: "title";
    color: pickone;
}
```

I recommend stay with "span". If you don't want to have a huge css with that extra stuff you can always do this in your html:

```
<span style="color:#000;">text</span>
```