# Style part of Wordpress category output with CSS?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In Wordpress, my categories are all two words, such as:

```
Name XXX
Name YYY
Name ZZZ
```

How can I style the X, Y, Z as bold and leave the Name as normal?

I can do so in the menu, simply by adding `<b>` tags around the X, Y and Z. But of course, this doesn't work in the Edit Category name field.

The category is output on the single post pages with:

`<?php $the_cat = get_the_category(); $category_link = get_category_link( $the_cat[0]->cat_ID ); foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo '<a class="'.$category->slug.'" href="'.$category_link.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>' ; } ?>`

Am I missing something really obvious here?! Thanks in advance, I'm going round in circles here! :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like this is possible without javascript. See this thread:

[CSS for changing color of last word in h1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268386/css-for-changing-color-of-last-word-in-h1)

Comment: This was a great idea - but it overwrote my CSS to style the category names by color. (`a.Name-XXX {color: #ff71cf;}`). So I tried Style-First-Word--jQuery-Plugin - so I set the category name to bold, but then the first word to be normal weight. Might be a bit ridiculous to do this in reverse - but it works! Thanks so much for leading me in the right direction.