# Mark space for :after content non-breaking

Tags: css

I'm adding a little graphic flag to the end of elements in a navigation using :after. For example

```
.navTreeItem .state-restricted:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Currently, if the little flag hits the end of the line it turns onto the next line by itself e.g.

```
- Navigation item one
  {flag}

- Navigation item two
```

However, to avoid widow flags I'd like the space before the flag to be non-breaking, so instead it would appear like this:

```
- Navigation item
  one {flag}

- Navigation item two
```

I can't use white-space: nowrap because I do want the text to be able to wrap. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `position: absolute; right: -10px; top: 0;`

Comment: that sort-of works, although if I use top: 0; it doesn't work on multi-line entries. It also makes the flag stick out over the edge of the space, which is sub-optimal.

Comment: If I give the list items a padding it deals with the overlap, but then I lose ~12px of width. hmmm

Comment: Actually, we're not getting consistent behaviour across different browsers for this one, so I don't think it's a runner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS for changing color of last word in h1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268386/css-for-changing-color-of-last-word-in-h1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m afraid the problem here is that when you set `display: inline-block` on the pseudo-element, it becomes an element that is treated as external to text (comparable to an image) and may be wrapped into the next line, even when it immediately follows a character. And if you let it default to `display: inline`, the `width` property does not apply to it, so it just doesn’t do what you want.

But you might consider a different approach. Instead of using CSS to create a visual object that looks like a filled circle, for example, you can use a character like U+25CF BLACK CIRCLE “●” and color it as desired. This sets obvious limitations, since shapes you would like to use might not exist as characters, or those characters might not be sufficiently well supported in fonts. But in simple cases, the approach might be feasible:

```css
.navTreeItem .state-restricted:after {
  content: "\25cf";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class=navTreeItem>
<div class=state-restricted>I really, really, really do want to prevent any
line break between this text and the :after pseudo-element.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That may be the best option. I've been looking into unicode and while I can't find exactly the icon I'm looking for I have found some alternatives the client may be happy with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**An adaptive CSS workaround**

Here is a workaround for one or several items with known content.
If you want to prevent the inline-block pseudo element from moving on the next line when the window/block width changes, you can set `max-with` for the item block at the media point where the moving happens (+ several pixels).
E.g.: moving is happening when the browser window width is 505px and the item width is 190px. Then you should use something like this:

```
@media(max-width: 510px){
    #item1{
            max-width: 180px;
    }
}
```

You have to ensure, that item with max-width 180px will wrap into

```
    - Navigation item
      one {flag}
```

**Limitations:**

- Won't do for items with dynamic content.
- You will need a unique CSS for each item.