# Give other color to last two letters of word of h1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one h1 tag and code looks like that

HTML

```
<h1>AwesoME</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
color:#eee
}

h1:last-word {
color:#000
}
```

I only want to change the **last two letters** of h1. Is it is possible with javascript or jQuery

Comment: <h1>Aweso<i>ME</i></h1>,  h1 i { color:#000;font-style:normal }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS for changing color of last word in h1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268386/css-for-changing-color-of-last-word-in-h1)

Comment: It is not a copy, I am asking my question dont you see it is written last two letters stupid

Answer (score 8):

Here's a jQuery solution:

```js
$('h1').html(function() {
  var txt= $(this).text();
  return txt.substr(0, txt.length-2)          //all but the last two characters
         + '<span>'+txt.slice(-2)+'</span>';  //put last two characters in a span
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color:#eee
}

h1 span {     /* different color for span */
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>AwesoME</h1>
```

---

Here's a vanilla JavaScript solution:

```js
var h1= document.querySelector('h1'),
    txt= h1.textContent;

h1.innerHTML= txt.substr(0, txt.length-2)          //all but the last two characters
              + '<span>'+txt.slice(-2)+'</span>';  //put last two characters in a span
```

```css
h1 {
  color:#eee
}

h1 span {     /* different color for span */
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>AwesoME</h1>
```

Comment: Just to be pedantic, OP did not specify the jQuery tag

Comment: True, but he wrote, "Is it is possible with javascript or jQuery."   Easy enough to do in vanilla JavaScript as well.

Comment: Added vanilla JavaScript solution.

Comment: Yes.  You could use `h1:hover` for the entire `h1`, or `h1 span:hover` for the `span` only.

Comment: Can i add id of h1 in js

Comment: Sure:  `document.querySelector('h1').id= 'myID'`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `css` `:after`

```css
h1 {
  color: #eee;
}
h1:after {
  content: "ME";
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  left:-50px;
}
```

```html
<h1>AwesoME</h1>
```