# How to select a first word of the last line of text? (<h1> - <h6>, <p> elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add a little horizontal line under each of the h1 - h6 elements on the site I am building. I am currently adding an after element:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: $altfont;
  position: relative;
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: $yellow;
  }
}
```

I also have a small jQuery function to make sure that the after element is always 20px below the element:

```
$(function () {
    $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function () {

            x = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
            $(this).css('line-height', (x + 20) + 'px');

    });
});
```

this works if the h1 has text-align left - when the text wraps into 2 or more lines, the after element will show up under the first word of the last line.

The problem is, if the text is center aligned, or right aligned, the after element will show up under the h1 element but not under the first word of the last line. Is this something that can be done with JS/JQuery?

Here is a pic of what happens. In the second example, I would like the yellow line to show up under the word "Slice".

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS for changing color of last word in h1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268386/css-for-changing-color-of-last-word-in-h1)

Comment: @Gerard The topic you linked to is about selecting the last word, not the first word of the last line.

Comment: The question is how to align the second line to the left while the whole h1 element ist text-aligne:center ?

Comment: @MFGSparka No. See the picture. When the line breaks, the yellow after element should be under the first word of the last line of thext.

Comment: @Varin Updated my answer to work with multiple elements and window resizing.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Thanks, I upvoted your answer yesterday, and I wish I could give 2 "accepted answer" marks as your solution is also great.

Comment: @Varin No problem at all. Yesterday I didn't have enough time to write complete answer. It was very nice time solving this task. Thank you for interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This was a nice challenge!
It takes 4 loops to achieve what you ask.

1. To add a `span` on each words.
2. To find the offset of the `span` on the last line.
3. To remove spans on all lines except the last.
4. To remove spans on all words except the first.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rwPYxM)

See comments in code *(I left all my debugging console.logs)*.

```js
$(function () {
  $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function () {

    x = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
    $(this).css('line-height', (x + 20) + 'px');

    findWord($(this));

  });

  function findWord(el){

    // Get the word array.
    var wordArr = el.html().split(" ");

    // Cycle words to add span on each words.
    for(i=0;i<wordArr.length;i++){
      console.log(wordArr[i]);
      wordArr[i] = "<span class='underliner'>"+wordArr[i]+"</span>";
    }

    // Update HTML.
    el.html(wordArr.join(" "));

    // Find the offset of the last line.
    var biggestOffset=0;
    el.find(".underliner").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).offset().top);
      if($(this).offset().top>biggestOffset){
        biggestOffset=$(this).offset().top;
      }
    });

    console.log("biggestOffset: "+biggestOffset);

    // Remove span on NOT the last line
    el.find(".underliner").each(function(){
      if($(this).offset().top<biggestOffset){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
      }
    });

    // On the last line, remove all spans except on the first word
    el.find(".underliner").not(":eq(0)").each(function(){
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
    });
  }
});
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  /*color: #333;*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: $altfont;
  position: relative;
  
  text-align:center;  /* ADDED */
  
  /* REMOVED */
  /*&:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: &yellow;
  }*/
}

.underliner{
  text-decoration:underline;
  text-decoration-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>This is a quite long H1 that will certainly wrap</h1>
<h2>This is a quite long H2 that will certainly wrap</h2>
<h3>This is a quite long H3 that will certainly wrap</h3>
<h4>This is a quite long H4 that will certainly wrap</h4>
<h5>This is a quite long H5 that will certainly wrap</h5>
<h6>This is a quite long H6 that will certainly wrap</h6>
```

---

**First answer**
*(misread the question...)*


Since you already use jQuery...

You can add `$(this).append($("<div class='smallBar'>").css({"top":x+10}))` to the script...
And use CSS to define `smallBar` the same way you did for the `after` pseudo element.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/RgEXLr?editors=1111)

```js
$(function () {
  $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function () {

    x = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
    $(this).css('line-height', (x + 20) + 'px');
    $(this).append($("<div class='smallBar'>").css({"top":x+10}))

  });
});
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  /*color: #333;*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: $altfont;
  position: relative;
  /*&:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: &yellow;
  }*/
}
.smallBar{
  position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a quite long H1 that will certainly wrap</h1>
<h2>This is a quite long H2 that will certainly wrap</h2>
<h3>This is a quite long H3 that will certainly wrap</h3>
<h4>This is a quite long H4 that will certainly wrap</h4>
<h5>This is a quite long H5 that will certainly wrap</h5>
<h6>This is a quite long H6 that will certainly wrap</h6>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it has to be the first word of last line after wrap, not the first word of first line.

Comment: Haaa!... I will think about it.

Comment: @DanielVickers: Don't use the edit system to comment.

Comment: Dude, I was half way through building this functionality myself, and already had three times more lines of code than you (parsing all the words to an array, removing them one by one and checking if the element's height is changing).

I adapted it for responsive as well: https://codepen.io/Varin/pen/LLqQjR

Thank you very much! one of the toughest problems to solve this year, and seems so simple

Comment: Good idea about the `.resize()` ;) Problems are always looking tought before the answer is found.

Answer (score 1):

My algorithm of finding and highlighting first word of last line:

1. Iterate through elements.
2. Get element's text (`innerText`).
3. Split text by whitespace (" ") sign.
4. Remove all elements from block.
5. Add `span`s with words and whitespace text nodes (also save this `span`s to array).
6. Sort this array by `span` with the highest `top` and lowest `left` of `span`'s rectangle.
7. Add highlighting class to the top element of this array.

```js
highlightFirstWordOfLastLineForHeaders();

/* apply highlighting on window resize */
window.addEventListener("resize", highlightFirstWordOfLastLineForHeaders);

/* Peforms highlightFirstWordOfLastLine call for every header element */
function highlightFirstWordOfLastLineForHeaders() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    highlightFirstWordOfLastLine(elements[i]);
  }
}

/* Peforms highlighting for single element */
function highlightFirstWordOfLastLine(element) {
  var text = element.innerText.trim();

  /* get words list */
  var words = text.split(" ");

  /* removing all elements */
  while (element.firstChild) {
    element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
  }

  var spanArray = [];

  /* add spans with words and whitespaces */
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    /* append span with word */
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(words[i]));
    element.appendChild(span);
    /* append whitespace */
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
    /* save span element to array */
    spanArray.push(span);
  }

  /* sorting by highest top and lowest left */
  spanArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var rectA = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rectB = b.getBoundingClientRect();

    var deltaTop = rectB.top - rectA.top;

    /* if differense is less then 1px */
    if (Math.abs(deltaTop) < 1) {
      return rectA.left - rectB.left;
    }

    return deltaTop;
  });

  /* appending highlighting to fist word of last line */
  spanArray[0].classList.add("selected");
}
```

```css
.selected {
  border-bottom: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ultrices porta nibh, eu semper massa ullamcorper et.
</h1>

<h2>
  Curabitur in venenatis sapien. Nullam cursus ante ac enim dapibus, a egestas tellus mollis.
</h2>

<h3>
  Aenean tincidunt ligula et egestas suscipit. Proin euismod felis leo, egestas porta purus porta vitae. Morbi ut pulvinar quam, eu accumsan eros. Duis tristique pretium imperdiet. Integer nunc odio, consectetur vel leo vel, posuere venenatis nunc. Vestibulum sit amet arcu sit amet tortor faucibus maximus in id massa. Praesent vulputate, tellus nec aliquam tempor, ipsum erat tincidunt est, sit amet cursus turpis dui ac ipsum. Duis nec odio in felis aliquet sagittis sit amet in leo. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur vitae sagittis diam. Duis id lectus cursus purus ultricies sollicitudin. Phasellus a ex sit amet eros lacinia fringilla sit amet sit amet sem. Proin luctus ornare risus at volutpat. Aliquam eleifend porttitor nulla. Sed facilisis mattis felis ut sodales.
</h3>

<h4>
  Quisque quis ultricies arcu. Aliquam feugiat non ipsum quis malesuada. Suspendisse ullamcorper, eros ut maximus hendrerit, sem velit lobortis turpis, non tristique justo magna eu nulla. Vestibulum maximus auctor ipsum sit amet finibus. Etiam commodo iaculis sem, vitae tincidunt libero. Phasellus lacus quam, semper ut pulvinar sed, accumsan a arcu. Suspendisse nulla velit, rhoncus id porttitor at, dictum ac ante. Sed eleifend vitae quam eget pretium.
</h4>

<h5>
  Duis semper rhoncus ultrices. Aliquam id elit nec quam fringilla gravida ac sed nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lorem leo, rhoncus quis nulla eget, posuere pellentesque leo. Nam in nisi sit amet sem consequat sodales. Quisque leo urna, aliquet eu malesuada at, laoreet et lorem. Fusce est neque, fringilla id ex id, semper tincidunt mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sodales sodales tincidunt. Pellentesque elementum quis neque vel malesuada. Nulla non scelerisque enim, ut posuere tortor. Fusce vel neque tristique ipsum aliquet mattis at sed sapien.
</h5>

<h6>
  Praesent scelerisque magna libero, vitae commodo purus tincidunt in. Etiam placerat diam turpis, sit amet iaculis eros efficitur at. Sed porta, dui non condimentum vestibulum, libero enim cursus nibh, eu luctus ligula ante sed neque. Duis vestibulum lacus felis, at iaculis tellus malesuada at. Donec vehicula lacinia metus. Pellentesque non efficitur lectus. Etiam et consectetur massa. Proin et leo cursus, convallis diam sit amet, mattis arcu. Fusce posuere pharetra leo eget volutpat. Maecenas et posuere urna. Nullam a dolor eu ipsum placerat rhoncus. In cursus, mauris ut pulvinar pellentesque, diam orci facilisis ante, at sollicitudin libero turpis in libero. In maximus est eu nisl venenatis ultrices.
</h6>
```

You can also see how it works with window resizing via [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10fugxho/).

Answer (score 0):

Although not tested this logic makes sense.

Write some JS that looks up the size of the h1, if the size of the h1 is greater than X which would be the size the h1 is with perhaps a little added on top for good measure.

Then add styling to the h1 with and :after pseudo class that appears bottom:0 left:0. this will however mean your text will have to be aligned left instead of center.

When the h1 wraps onto 2 lines the h1 size essentially doubles which will then cause the if statement to fire and add the styling to the text. This is the closest answer I have to perfect for you I apologise if you require the text to be central.

**EDIT: Example code of above**.

Now I can't say this will work but here is some basic code around based on the previously explained method. Im not amazing with javascript so you will more than likely need to build on. But at least this gives you a starting point I hope...

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var h1Height = document.getElementsByTagName("h1").offsetHeight;

function firstH1Wrap() {
    if (h1Height < /*line-height+5px*/){
        document.getElementsByTagName("h1").addClass('hide-line');
    } else {
        document.getElementsByTagName("h1").removeClass('hide-line');
    }
}
});

$(window).resize(firstH1Wrap).trigger('resize')
```

CSS

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    font-family: $altfont;
    position: relative;
}

h1:after, h2:after, h3:after, h4:after, h5:after, h6:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: $yellow;
    display: block;
}

h1.hide-line:after, h2.hide-line:after, h3.hide-line:after, h4.hide-line:after, h5.hide-line:after, h6.hide-line:after {
    display: none;
}
```

If you was to set the line height of all the Headings 1-6 the same you could run the same function for all of them as they have the same sizing, if you don't then you'll need to declare a new variable for each of the headings and build it into the function or make new ones.

Comment: he doesnt want a line under the whole text,or the whole first word

Comment: First word of LAST LINE of text. So when the line breaks into 2 lines, the yellow after element will show up under the first word in the second line.

Comment: I'm working with a responsive design CMS here. It has to be happening dynamically. As I resize the window and the line breaks, the yellow underline should snap to the first word of last line, when the element wraps to 2 or more lines.

Comment: Edited with a quick example of what the basic structure of the code would be.

Comment: Also the reason why the line appears where it does on your current code is because the absolute position is set to the bottom left, perhaps if you added a % for the left it may be able to cover the text. @Varin

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to fix based on the way you wrote the code. But I think I have a solution if you are willing to change a few things. My method will only work if you know the `font-size` property of the element you are addressing.

**UPDATED CSS**

```
h1 {
  font-size: 24px; /* ADDED */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-family: $altfont;
  position: relative;

  &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 24px; /* FONT SIZE = DISTANCE */
      left:0;
      width: 60px;
      height: 4px;
      background-color: $yellow;
  }
}
```

This should work however it is untested.

It works by knowing the `font-size` and then using that value as a top margin. So it will always be in the same location regardless in the text alignment changes.

**EDIT: I now understand what you would like to accomplish.**

This is very difficult to do because the line could be in many different locations. The only solution I can think of from the top of my head is:

**Media Queries**

You would need to create a breakpoint anytime and everytime the text wraps or the first word of the last line moves.

Comment: The after element should show under the first word of LAST LINE of text, when the line breaks into two or more lines. Just like on the picture in the original post, the yellow line should show under the word "SLICE" in the second line after the line have wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $(this:last).text().trim().split(" ");
var last = text.pop();
$( this:last).html(text.join(" ") + (text.length > 0 ? " <span class='lastWord'>" + last + "</span>" : last));
};
```

And in the CSS add this

```
 .lastWord{text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: This selects the last word, not the first word of the last line.

Answer (score -3):

just put a

```
top:'whatever is line-height + 20px'
```

to the :after element (and remove bottom)

edit:nm
i missed the ' I would like the yellow line to show up under the word "Slice".' part