# how to style the last word in the title with underline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have same title style like below

[image]

My problem is to have the underline, I tried using `title:after` but I didn't get the exact effect that I need

My Code

```
<h1>Sign In</h1>

<style>
  h1:after{
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 102px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(40,84,161,1);
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you share the html and the css? Are you using a certain bootstrap component?

Comment: The best approach is using a span element to wrap the last word and style it with a border-bottom.

Comment: If you want to do this automatically it is not possible with pure CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9268874/11151040

Comment: I'm not very clear what you want to do as in the example you give the 'underline' goes under more than just the last word. Perhaps if you could give more examples, or is it just for the words Sign In?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to split the content of the title and wrap the last word in a span to style it with a `border-bottom`.

In the example I show you how to do it with a reusable funcion that will wrap the last word no matter the size of the string.

```js
function underlineLastWord(element)
{
    var pieces = element.innerHTML.split(" ");
    var last = pieces.pop();
    var first = pieces.join(" ");
    element.innerHTML = first + "<span> " + last + "</span>";
}

var elements =  document.querySelectorAll(".underline-end");
elements.forEach(x => underlineLastWord(x));
```

```css
  .underline-end > span {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
 }
```

```html
<h1 class="underline-end">Sign in up<h1>
<h1 class="underline-end">Sign in<h1>
<h1 class="underline-end">Sign<h1>
<h1 class="underline-end">Something even longer<h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Sign <span class="text-underline">In</span><h1>

<style>
  .text-underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: blue;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: A `<div>` in `<h1>` doesn't make sense. A `<span>` would be more practical

Comment: sorry, force of habit, maybe change the <div> with <span>

Answer (score 0):

Put the words you want underlined inside `<u>` tags. Example:

```
<h1>Sign <u>In</u></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it purely with CSS.
If it's going to reoccur throughout the project, try using [lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) then the following will work:

```
h1
{
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1::last-word
{
  text-decoration:underline rgba(40,84,161,1);
}
```

If this a rare occurance, wrap the last word in a div or span tag (as the other contributors - who got their answers in while I was writing this - have suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Method1:

Just use the default html tag for underline it will automatically do the underline for you for this to work you have wrap the text that you want to underline in the u tag example below:

```
<h1>Sign <u>In</u></h1>
```

Method2:

You use css to manually specify the text decoration properties see below

```
<h1>Sign <span class="ul">In</span></h1>
```

In css file

```
.ul {
   text-decoration: underline;
 }
```