# I have {{data}} in angular. this {{data}} holds a sentence with "name" or "class" . i want to add colour to name or class using ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a code that looks like:

```
<mat-panel-title>
    {{data}}
</mat-panel-title>
```

This {{data}} is a variable that holds a sentence like `My **name** is Sam`, 'My **country** is greece'. The name and country are variables too, which is at a position of : info[""][''][0] belonging to {{data}} . i would want to add a different colour to only "info[""][''][0]" position by using a ts file. I would really love if you could please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS for changing color of last word in h1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268386/css-for-changing-color-of-last-word-in-h1)

Answer (score 1):

try to create a directive :

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

 
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.changeColor(el);
 }

 changeColor(el: ElementRef) {
  
   //call the  el.nativeElement.style.color  and put your logic.....
 
 }

}
```

then call it by the selector  :

```
<h1 highlight>{{data}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

write a function that returns the name as the last word and also the sentence without name:

```
getPartsOfSentence(data: string){
const x = text.split(" ");
 const name = x[x.length-1];
 const sentenceWithoutName = x.slice(0, -1).join(" ");
return ({name, sentenceWithoutName});
}
```

deconstruct two variables and use them separately in your html and style them:

```
const {name, sentenceWithoutName} = getPartsOfSentence(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

1. The regExpr should be like

   ```
   const regText = '(' + x + ')([.,\\s])|(\\s)(' + x + '$)';
   const reg = new RegExp(regText, 'gi');
   text = text.replace(reg, '$3<strong>$1$4</strong>$2');
   ```

   a word+(or , or . or \s) or if it's at end \s+word+
2. And in the getter we need change this.oldValue

   ```
     @Input() set showHighlight(words: any) {
       if (!Array.isArray(words)) this.words = [words];
       else this.words = words;
       this.oldValue=null
     }
   ```

(just corrected in code)

**Original**

The typical solution to do it is use a pipe, that transform a string in an HTML replace the words indicate by `<strong>word</strong>` using reg expressions.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight',
})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitize: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let text = value;
    if (args) {
      if (!Array.isArray(args)) args = [args];

      args.forEach((x) => {
         const regText = '(' + x + ')([.,\\s])|(\\s)(' + x + '$)';
         const reg = new RegExp(regText, 'gi');
         text = text.replace(reg, '$3<strong>$1$4</strong>$2');
      });
      text =text.replace(/\n/g,'<br/>')
    }
    return this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text);
  }
}
```

La reg expression `'(' + x + ')([.,\\s])|(' + x + '$)'` capture in $1 or $3 the word replaced and in $2 a space, a comma or a point.

And use in the way

```
<div class="highlight" [innerHTML]="data|highlight:'name'"></div>
```

See that I choose to this pipe you can use also an array, e.g.

```
<div class="highlight" [innerHTML]="data|highlight:['name','boy']"></div>
```

Really I don't like so much the use of innerHTML and sanitize, so we are going to try a directive than can be used in the way

```
<p [showHighlight]="['house','red']" >In the house the red skin wait</p>
or
<p [showHighlight]="['house','red']" >{{data}}</p>
```

For this we are going to use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). The idea is create a "div", hidden the content, and each change in content add to the created div the innerHTML.

As we are going to use ngAfterContentChecked -and this event is executed several times, we store in a variable "oldValue" the innerHTML.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[showHighlight]',
})
export class HighlightDirective implements AfterContentChecked {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  private words: string[] = [];
  private div: any = null;
  private oldValue: any;

  //in Input use a setter to create an array if it's only one string
  @Input() set showHighlight(words: any) {
    if (!Array.isArray(words)) this.words = [words];
    else this.words = words;
    this.oldValue=null
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    //we get the el.nativeElement.innerHTML
    //If is diferent than the "oldValue"

    if (this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML != this.oldValue) {
      //we store the value
      this.oldValue = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;

      //get the text
      let text = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;

      //iterate over the words array
      this.words.forEach((x) => {

        //use the reg expresion to replace
        const regText = '(' + x + ')([.,\\s])|(\\s)(' + x + '$)';
        const reg = new RegExp(regText, 'gi');
        text = text.replace(reg, '$3<strong>$1$4</strong>$2');
      });

      //replace also \n by <br/>
      text =text.replace(/\n/g,'<br/>')

      //if we've not yet create the div 
      if (!this.div) {
        //we create the div with the same "tagName" than the element
        this.div = this.renderer.createElement(
          this.el.nativeElement.tagName.toLowerCase()
        );

        //Add a class 'highlight'
        this.renderer.addClass(this.div, 'highlight');

        //And insert in parent just before the element
        this.renderer.insertBefore(
          this.el.nativeElement.parentElement,
          this.div,
          this.el.nativeElement
        );

        //finally we use style.display:'none' to hide the element
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
      }

      //If there a change change the innerHTML of the div
      this.renderer.setProperty(this.div, 'innerHTML', text);
    }
  }
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmqx3x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight.directive.ts,src%2Fstyles.css) with the two approach

NOTE: I choose reemplace the "word" by `<strong>word</strong>`, I add a class to the div 'hightlight' to change the css in **styles.css** in the way

```
.highlight strong {
  color: red;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```